# Why my FLATTR button doesn't appear in spanish language?

Tags: flattr

i'm new using FLATTR (indeed a great project!), and after read and read the official doc page i cannot configure well my button auto-submit.

The website where i'm inserting the FLATTR button is a culture blog-site (for example: [kultube.net/sonora](http://kultube.net/sonora/index.php?pag=m_blog&gad=detalle_entrada&entry=14&tags=literatura&n_pag=1)), with content in spanish. But all appear in english (title emergent over the button image, and the popup window explaining what is FLATTR to people don't logged).

I used this code at header of all pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    (function() {
        var s = document.createElement('script'), t = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'http://api.flattr.com/js/0.6/load.js?mode=auto&language=es_ES';
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
    })();
/* ]]> */</script>
```

And this is the code for the button:

```
 <a class="FlattrButton" style="display:none;" 
     rev="flattr;button:compact;" 
     href="https://flattr.com/profile/caos30"></a>

 <noscript>
  <a href="http://flattr.com/thing/470497/caos30-on-Flattr" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://api.flattr.com/button/flattr-badge-large.png" alt="Flattr this" title="Flattr this" border="0" /></a>
 </noscript>
```

I need that it appear in spanish (specially the popup window for expose what is FLATTR) for accomplish to attract more spanish users to this great project.

If you need this, i can traduce very fast the popup content to spanish. It's a simple thing. Thanks in advance to Flattr team.

SERGI

Answer (score 1):

The whole language localisation is very poor at the moment. This is also for German language: Buttons, button-tooltips and many important parts of the flattr-site still are in plain english.